# iOS objc/runtime method_exchangeImplementations

Tags: ios

*i did it in NSMutableArray:*

```
+load{

        Method fromMethod1 = class_getInstanceMethod(objc_getClass("__NSArrayM"),      @selector(addObject:));
        Method toMethod1 = class_getInstanceMethod(objc_getClass("__NSArrayM"), @selector(ww_addObject:));
        method_exchangeImplementations(fromMethod1, toMethod1);
}


static int number = 0;

-(void)ww_addObject:(id)anObject
{
    NSLog(@"ww_addObject run as :%d times ",number ++);
    if (anObject == nil) {
        return;
    }

    [self ww_addObject:anObject];
}
```

then run it in demo , log like this:

```
209901] ww_addObject run as :1076 times 
2016-12-22 15:40:00.071 testArr[12062:209901] ww_addObject run as :1077 times 
2016-12-22 15:40:00.071 testArr[12062:209901] ww_addObject run as :1078 times
```

why it run as 1078 times???

my test code:

```
NSMutableArray  *arr = [@[@"11",@"22",@"33"] mutableCopy];
[arr addObject:nil];
```

Comment: Have you noticed you are calling again and again the same method recursively?

Comment: thanks,i have add the test code .

Comment: Again...you're calling recursively your `ww_addObject:` method. It runs even more than 1078 times, but iOS kills the app before it consumes all the memory

Comment: You replace the addObject: method of `NSMutableArray`, it also affects the frameworks you linked with for example `UIKit`.